# Como puedo copiar datos de una columna en una tabla a otra tabla en postgresql?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, phpmyadmin, tablas

Tengo una tabla llamada `contabb1` a la cual le he creado una tabla de *respaldo* usando la sentencia:

```
CREATE TABLE "BDprueba".contabb1backup AS SELECT * FROM "public".contabb1;
```

He modificado unos datos dentro de la tabla original por error y necesito recuperar los originales que había en una sola columna.

El nombre de esa columna es `Pereje`. ¿Cómo puedo copiar los datos de esa columna solamente que se encuentran en la copia y colocarlos nuevamente en la tabla original?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la llave primaria de las tablas? ¿Hablamos de postgreSQL o de MySQL? Pregunto porque tus etiquetas son confusas...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una subconsulta que te devuelva los registro y a esta le aplicas `where` para filtrar por el `id` que deberia tener

Ejemplo:

```
 UPDATE "public".contabb1
    SET "public".contabb1.Pereje=tablaBack.Pereje
    FROM (select * FROM "BDprueba".contabb1backup) as tablaBack
    WHERE "public".contabb1.id=tablaBack.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la clave primaria en ambas tablas es `id` y que ambas están en la misma base de datos:

```
UPDATE contabb1
  set pereje=contabb1backup.pereje
  from contabb1backup
  where contabb1.id=contabb1backup.id;
```

Aporto los dataset en [Postgres14 en dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=95963b73909c646cd4278f914900723d) y [MySQL8.0 en dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=877272a615e669e0472403bb5b1be8b1)